# Exception Class not working

Tags: java, exception, io, compiler-errors

I have a program that I'm trying to make throw a certain exception. I've created a custom Exception class here:

```
import java.io.*;

public class ShapeException extends Exception
{
   public ShapeException(String message)
   {
      super(message);
   }
}
```

Here is the class where I try and implement the Exception:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Circle
{      
   private double radius;  

   public Circle(double inRadius )
   {
      if(inRadius < 0.0)
      {
         throw new ShapeException("Shape Exception Occurred...");
      }
      else
      {
         radius = inRadius;
      }
   }

   public double getRadius()
   {
      return radius;
   }

   public void setRadius(double newRadius)
   {
      if(newRadius < 0.0)
      {
         throw new ShapeException("Shape Exception Occurred...");
      }
      else
      {
         radius = newRadius;
      }
   }

   public double area()
   {
      return Math.PI * radius * radius;
   }

   public void stretchBy(double factor )
   {
      if(factor < 0.0)
      {
         throw new ShapeException("Shape Exception Occurred...");
      }
      else
      {
         radius = radius * factor;
      }
   }

   public String toString()
   {
       return "Circle Radius: " + radius; 
   }
}
```

However, this will not compile and gives me errors telling me that my shape exception error must be caught or declared to be thrown. What am I doing wrong? Is this not declared?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html

Comment: Read the errors. Google them if you have to. The compiler is not just having a bad day and picking on you. They mean something! `shape exception error must be caught or declared to be thrown`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java whenever you throw a checked exception you need to declare it in the method signature with `throws` keyword. Below is the code snippet which are not having any compilation errors because each method has `throws` declaration wherever `ShapeException` is thrown.

```
public class Circle {
    private double radius;

    public Circle(double inRadius) throws ShapeException {
        if(inRadius < 0.0) {
            throw new ShapeException("Shape Exception Occurred...");
        } else {
            radius = inRadius;
        }
    }

    public double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    public void setRadius(double newRadius) throws ShapeException {
        if(newRadius < 0.0) {
            throw new ShapeException("Shape Exception Occurred...");
        } else {
            radius = newRadius;
        }
    }

    public double area() {
        return Math.PI * radius * radius;
    }

    public void stretchBy(double factor) throws ShapeException {
        if(factor < 0.0) {
            throw new ShapeException("Shape Exception Occurred...");
        } else {
            radius = radius * factor;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Circle Radius: " + radius;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java there are two types of [Exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html). The one you are using is called [Checked Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation), which is used for recoverable errors. When Checked Exception is thrown you have to handle it. Either you handle it where it occurs with a [try-catch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html) block.

```
try {
    methodThrowingShapeException()
} catch (ShapeException e) {
    // Log and handle the Exception
}
```

**Never leave catch block empty!**

Or you can declare it to be thrown in method signature in which case exception has to be handled by caller of the method.

```
public void setRadius(double newRadius) throws ShapeException
```